# 301 Redirect Whole Site Except One Folder, leave Add-on domains alone

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a brainteaser and need help from people smarter than me. I have a shared hosting account. I'd like to 301 forward the root URL (say, domain.org) to a new URL. I also want one folder (/blog/) to be left alone (not forwarded). I was able to find an example of this here, and I put together this potential scenario for doing that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I believe that this should be OK, but here's the trick: I have add-on domains in this hosting, and if I use the above, I'm pretty sure that I will forward every one of them to newdomain.org, not just domain.org. I did some testing using more specific text strings in the first spot following RewriteRule, but I can't seem to get the syntax without blowing up my site and getting a 500.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Where *domain.org* is the domain that you want everything to be redirected to *newdomain.org*, except `/blog/`.

Comment: Thanks! Elegantly simple, my test worked fine! Other domains worked, the first one forwarded to the new one, and the /blog/ area did its thing. Now I'm thinking that I might try chaining some more commands together and see if that works. My plan is to have the /blog/ one forward to one URL, and then "everything else" forward to another one. I'll probably test on local server.  

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org/blog/$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain-one.org/$1 [L,R=301]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain-two.org/$1 [L,R=301]`